# What did cause the war between Marleyans and Eldians?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm finding answers for my book. It's about a war between Marleyans and Eldians but it did not tell in the manga what caused the war so I was looking for some help.

Comment: for someone who doesnt read the manga, i sure got implicitly spoiled.

Answer (score 1):

**Major manga spoilers below!**

> After obtaining power of Titans, eldians started massive ethnic cleansing, and marlians became one of the victims of this act, naturally inflicting massive hatred towards eldians.

[Source](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Marley)